# Undefined variable: updates - in Homepage Sponzy template

Tags: php, laravel, variables, undefined

I have tried to call the function "@include('includes.updates')" and it throws me the error "ErrorException
Undefined variable: updates"

In hompage there are other functions like " @include('includes.listing-creators')" that when called work normally but I don't know why "include.updates" doesn't work.

```
@if ($updates->total() != 0)
 <div class="grid-updates position-relative" id="updatesPaginator">
    @include('includes.updates')
 </div> 
@endif
```

The code "@include('includes.updates')" should call the list of posts published by users, it is not working on homepage as I mentioned before. Could someone help me how to call the function to make it work on homepage?

I share link of the code that I am using and I want to modify:
https://codecanyon.net/item/sponzy-support-creators-content-script/28416726

Comment: It's probably throwing the error on `@if ($updates->total() != 0)`, so try `@if (!empty($updates) && $updates->total() != 0)`

Comment: the condition you mentioned to me has no error, but it doesn't show any content. Apparently because the problem that the home page is not related to the use of that function remains the same. I would like to know how to make Home if it takes into account the "include.updates"

Comment: Maybe a typo? You are constantly mentioning ```include.updates```, yet your code contains ```includes.updates```...